# Expand and collapse items logic

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, sveltekit

The logic is:

- Expand always shows all the available items.
- By default, only a maximum of two items is displayed.
- The selected items should always be at the top of the list.
- If there are more than two items selected, show all of them while
  collapsing.
- When we have nothing selected, again show a maximum of two items.
- When we have only one selected, show one selected and one not
  selected to maintain the minimum of two.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
  let checkboxes = [
    { id: 1, label: 'Checkbox 1', checked: false },
    { id: 2, label: 'Checkbox 2', checked: false },
    { id: 3, label: 'Checkbox 3', checked: false },
    { id: 4, label: 'Checkbox 4', checked: false },
        { id: 5, label: 'Checkbox 5', checked: false },
        { id: 6, label: 'Checkbox 6', checked: false },

    // Add more checkboxes as needed
  ];

  let isExpanded = false;

  function toggleExpand() {
    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
  }
</script>


<div class="checkbox-list">
  {#each (isExpanded ? checkboxes : checkboxes.slice(0, 2)) as checkbox (checkbox.id)}
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={checkbox.checked} />
      {checkbox.label}
    </label>
  {/each}
  {#if checkboxes.length > 2}
    <button on:click={toggleExpand}>
      {#if isExpanded}Collapse{:else}Expand{/if}
    </button>
  {/if}
</div>

<style>
    div { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }

    label:has(input:checked) {
        order: -9999;
    }
</style>
```

I do not know which approach is the best for doing this.
You can also use this svelte playground to test the current implementation:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-brc2tj?file=src%2Froutes%2F%2Bpage.svelte

Comment: Try it:  `{#each (isExpanded ? checkboxes : checkboxes.filter((el)=>{return el.checked==true}).length>0?checkboxes.filter((el)=>{return el.checked==true}):checkboxes.slice(0,2)) as checkbox (checkbox.id)}`

Comment: @VivekanandVishvkarma Does not work properly. Does not follow the logic.